# Evaluating general integrals with inverses

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

consider we have the inverse of a function evaluated at q

$x=f^{-1}(q)$

is there a trick for evaluating the integral of the function where one f the limits of integration is the inverse of the function evaluated at point q

$\int_{x}^{1}f(y)\, dy$

I know for trigometric functions it's easy but i'm sure there is a method to evulate general integrals in this way